# .bat file failing to run when clicked

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created a .bat file that will move 3 files from an SFTP site to a local server. When I copy and paste the code into cmd then it works fine. If I double click on the batch file then it fails giving error statements saying:

xxxx\xxxx\xxxx cmd.exe was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. D3faulting to Windows directory.
Access denied
Access denied
Error opening script file ftpcmd.dat

And so on.

Why would the code work fine with copy and paste?
I have run as administrator.

Can someone help please?

Comment: "UNC paths are not supported" = you can only run batch files that are stored on a hard drive that's local to your PC.

Comment: Thanks!That would make sense, although there are batch files in the same folder that run when clicked. I'll go and give that a go.